# Please can somebody analyse this circuit

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, parallel, kirchhoffs-laws

I am struggling to find the value of resistor x, I have tried a few ideas such as treating the 4 resistors as a 4 way parallel, also getting Rt of the 10 and 15 Ohm resistors, then working backwards through total resistance (which I know is 16 Ohm). But cant find how this is done. I know the answer is 12 Ohm but I do not know how to get to this point.

[image]

Comment: Hint : You know Power and Volts, does that tell you any useful information?

Comment: So I know that the Current is 15A (3600/240). And that means the total resistance is 16 Ohm (240/15). I have tried rearranging the "parallel circuit total resistance" formula to make x the subject but to no avail, this leads me to believe that its not a parallel circuit. but my problem is if thats not the case then i cant figure out what it IS

Comment: So what would the voltage across the 10 and 15 Ohm resistors be?

Comment: That would be 144V across the 10 Ohm , and 96V across the 15 Ohm

Comment: Not exactly, they are in parallel, so the voltage across them has to be the same.

Comment: Oops ! sorry that was current divider, yes the voltages across the first two must be the same :) I realise I can treat the 10 and 15 ohm as one 6 ohm (1/((1/10)+(1/15)). so the 15 Amps is splitting between the 60 ohm and x ohm, how would I work out their ratios if i only know one ?

Comment: Same formula -- but now the unknown is in a different place, so you need to solve for it.

Comment: got it ! rearranging 16 = $$6 + (1 / (1/60) + (1/x) )$$ gives $$1/((1/10) - (1/60)) = x$$

Comment: Can someone explain how I lost 7 points for this question ?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, this is not a simple parallel circuit.

The resistors 10 and 15 are in parallel. The resistors 60 and X are in parallel.

HOWEVER 10 and 15 combined are in *series* with 60 and x combined.

The way to understand this is to first combine the 10 and 15 into 6 ohms, and redraw the picture. I think the way it is drawn is what is so confusing about this problem.

Now you know the total is 16 ohms, and the first two combined are 6ohms of the total. The 60 and the X must equal 10 ohms.

1/60 + 1/x = 1/10

Comment: Oh, I just saw there were more comments hidden. Looks like you already figured this one out. I'm new at this site.